# List Index out of range - using open cv

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook

Here's the piece of code i'm getting my error in:

```
img= frames[680]
testimg= cv2.resize(img, _MODEL_SIZE)

testimg=testimg.reshape(1,416,416,3)

detection_result = sess.run(detections, feed_dict={inputs: testimg})
```

and the code used above is:

```
FOI= 0.2
_vid_path 
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(_vid_path)
frames= []
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==False:
        break
    else:
            frames.append(frame)
            
frm_idxes = np.round(np.linspace(0,len(frames)-1,int(len(frames)*FOI))).astype(int)
```

im getting the list out of index when im running the latter piece of code and it appears it wont take any value and give me the result.